# Debian/Ubuntu: How to select predefined collections after installation

Tags: ubuntu, debian, installation

How do I select predefined collections (those you can select during installation of Ubuntu) after the installation? I read somewhere this is possible, can't for my life find where though.

[image: Predefined collections]
<sub>(source: [ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/lamp9/31.png))</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tasksel --list-tasks
```

will lists all the possible tasks you can install.

```
tasksel install <task>
```

will install it.

```
man tasksel
```

is your friend.

Comment: Thanks a billion! Just what I was looking for. Running just "tasksel" brings up the GUI in the picture, btw

Comment: Googled and found my own Q. Seems you have to install `tasksel` yourself in 11.04.